# A formula of intersection product in Fulton's Intersection Theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is **Example 8.1.13** in Fulton's *Intersection Theory*.

> Consider fiber square
> \begin{equation}
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> X' @>^{f'} >> Y'\\
> @V^{h}VV @V^{g} VV\\
> X @>_{f} >> Y
> \end{CD}
> \end{equation}
> with $Y,Y'$ non-singular and $g$ be a closed embedding of codim $d$ with normal bundle $N$. Then for $x\in\mathrm{CH}_*(X'),y\in\mathrm{CH}_*(Y')$, we need to show that
> $$h_*(x)\cdot_fg_*(y)=h_*(c_d((f')^*N)\cap(x\cdot_{f'}y))$$
> in $\mathrm{CH}_*(X)$.

As we can get
\begin{equation}
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X'\times_YY' @> >> X'\times Y'\\
@V^{F}VV @V^{h\times g} VV\\
X @>_{\gamma_f} >> X\times Y
\end{CD}
\end{equation}
hence $$h_*(x)\cdot_fg_*(y)=\gamma_f^!(h_*(x)\times g_*(y))=F_*(\gamma_f^!(x\times y))$$
and
$$h_*(c_d((f')^*N)\cap(x\cdot_{f'}y))=h_*(c_d((f')^*N)\cap(\gamma_{f'}^!(x\times y))).$$
But I don't know how to connected $\gamma_f$ and $\gamma_{f'}$ and connected the excess intersection formula to $N$?

Thank you very much!!!